# Multiple Instances of the same Fragment in a FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a FragmentStatePagerAdapter which displays different instances of the same fragment but having different data, as shown:

```
class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdpater{

    public MyAdapter (FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int i){
        Frag f = new Frag();
        f.setState(i);   //sets the value of the "State" instance variable 
                         //of the fragment
        return f;
    }

    public int getCount(){
    return 100;
    }
}
```

Now, my question is that as the FragmentStatePagerAdapter saves the state of a fragment instance before it destroys them, and as the different instances may have different data saved in the onSaveInstanceState, **then how does the FragmentStatePagerAdapter decide which savedInstanceState to be restored on re-creation of the Fragment instances** when they need to be re-displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code to [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v13/java/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java), it looks like the state is saved and restored based on position.

Comment: Can you please tell me which line no. in the source code? I cannot seem to find what you are saying.

Comment: Look at the usages of `mSavedState`. They are always indexed based on the position of the fragment they pertain to.